# Angular, Rails, Firefox, and REST?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, rest, firefox

I've been going through this tutorial on Angular and Rails: https://thinkster.io/angular-rails

I've gotten all the way to the "Wiring Everything Up > Upvoting Posts" part. When an upvote icon is clicked the webpage is supposed to make the appropriate ajax call to the rails server (something along the lines of: `PUT /posts/:id/upvote.json`). The problem is that whenever I use Firefox I get this mysterious "`no element found`" error every time I upvote a post.

[image]

If you click on the "upvote.json:1:1" link in the console you are shown raw html for a rails error page. The page says something about an invalid request of the form: `GET /posts/:id/upvote.json`. However the output from the rails server shows no evidence of such a faulty request. If you go to the network tab of the Firefox developer tools you will likewise see no such faulty GET request. I even downloaded Wireshark and ran a packet trace, and similarly found no bad GET request, only the correct PUT one. I've tested it in Chromium and Midori (I'm on linux) and it works fine.

My guess is that Firefox somehow thinks that there is a file named upvote.json and it somehow tries to download it form the rails server?

Here is my function for making the request:

```
o.upvote = function (post) {
  $http({
    url: '/posts/' + post.id + '/upvote.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'PUT'
  }).then(
    function success(resp) {
      console.log('--------- success ----------');
      console.log(resp);
      post.upvotes += 1;
    },
    function error(resp) {
      console.log('--------- error ----------');
      console.log(resp)
    });
};
```

Here is output from the rails server for the PUT request:

```
Started PUT "/posts/1/upvote.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-12 23:22:45 -0500
Processing by PostsController#upvote as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
{"controller"=>"posts", "action"=>"upvote", "id"=>"1", "format"=>"json"}
  Post Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE `posts` SET `upvotes` = 25, `updated_at` = '2016-01-13 04:22:45' WHERE `posts`.`id` = 1
   (14.0ms)  COMMIT
Completed 204 No Content in 30ms (ActiveRecord: 15.7ms)
```

Rake routes:

```
             Prefix Verb URI Pattern                                   Controller#Action
upvote_post_comment PUT  /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/upvote(.:format) comments#upvote
      post_comments POST /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)            comments#create
       post_comment GET  /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)        comments#show
        upvote_post PUT  /posts/:id/upvote(.:format)                   posts#upvote
              posts GET  /posts(.:format)                              posts#index
                    POST /posts(.:format)                              posts#create
               post GET  /posts/:id(.:format)                          posts#show
               root GET  /                                             main#angular
```

Controller:

```
respond_to :json

def upvote
  puts "#{params.inspect}"
  post = Post.find(params[:id])
  post.increment!(:upvotes)

  respond_with post
end
```

Is this a problem with Firefox or me?

Edit

Firefox seems to be trying to parse the rails error page (html) as if it were json. It shows an error on the first line of "upvotes.json" as `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Edit

Fixed it by changing my controller code from:

```
respond_with post
```

to

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: post }
end
```

Comment: Your code is successfully fetching the action... and has returned a response that it has labelled 'upvote.json' and the error is occurring in line 1 of that response... can you show us what comes back in those responses? (don't put it in comments, but edit your question and put it there so we get good  code formatting).

Comment: "if you click on the "upvote.json:1:1" link in the console you are shown raw html for a rails error page." - usually it will also take you to roughly the line of code that is throwing the error.. can you show us the relevant snippet of that?

Comment: It's just: `<!DOCTYPE html>` it's obvious now what's going wrong. Firefox is trying to parse the html as if it were json...I still have no clue why though

Comment: ok, so perhaps your controller isn't actually returning what you think it's returning? Thinking about it... do you really need to return anything at all in your controller apart from "success/failure" ? That would make things simpler from the js end.